# center an id in a html page using css

Tags: html, css

this is my code:

```
   <div id="content">   
        <div id="slider1">
            <div class = "content-dir">
                  <h1>Anno 2012</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I would center `slider1`. I used `margin: 0 auto` but it didn't work.

The style applied to id `content` is only `height`

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
#content {
    text-align: center;
}
#slider1 {
    width: 400px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

This works on both IE and modern browsers.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work.I would center slider1 element.how can i do?

Comment: Make sure #content has `width: 100%;`

Comment: I was going to suggest something very similar to MMM's solution - just without the text-align properties. As long as you define the width of the element you want to center (#slider1), margin: 0 auto; should work. See http://jsfiddle.net/BSsTU/

Comment: how old are we talking? I'm pretty sure it's fine in at least 7 and up, possibly 6.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the problem is because of "content" div .because slider div is inside content . set a width and margin for "content" div then check again

```
#Content
{
  width:600px;
  margin : auto;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Give it a width and display: block !

Comment: A Width and display:Block is Necessary when you want to Center horizontally. You are right that, that a DIV is in default Block, but that are the requirements !

Comment: Indeed, but that's one of many things that are needed and these two things won't make an element centred...

Comment: Mate, first of all you've added `margin: 0px auto;`, secondly you are setting `display` to `block` and a div is already a `block` so this is bad advice.

Comment: the block on div is helpful for preventing an overide and to generalize the alignment. Mazzy already wrote »I used margin: 0 auto but it didn't work« , and my Answer is an addition to his question.

Comment: It won't prevent an override since a statement with higher specificity will override it anyway.